# How to redirect from html page to view and post data in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

First I post some data from my view to an html page:

view.py

```
def export(request):
    primary_key = request.GET.get('primary_key')
    selected_peer = Peer.objects.get(pk=int(primary_key))
    template= loader.get_template('delete-peer.html')

    content= {
         'selected_peer':selected_peer,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(content,request))
```

the selected_peer will be sent to the html page

I have a HTML page as below:

```
{% block content %}

<div class="submit-row">
<p> {{ selected_peer.address }}</p>
<input type="submit" value="Delete Peer" name="_delete-confirm">
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

I can use the data (content) in my Html page.

Now I have a button (Delete Peer) and I want to redirect on click to another view and post the data (selected_peer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% block content %}

<div class="submit-row">
<form action="your_view_url" method="post">
<input type='hidden' name="address" value="{{ selected_peer.address }}">
<p> {{ selected_peer.address }}</p>
<input type="submit" value="Delete Peer" name="_delete-confirm">
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

this should do it. add a form and give the url of the view you want to post data to

Comment: thanks how can I send all data from selected_peer because it have more data. because i want to use these data in another view.